# Execute python script and get output with php wamp on windows

Tags: python, php

I am trying to execute a python script with php on windows using wamp server.

I need to also command output. I could not  execute python script.

I tried like this:

```
<?php

    $command = escapeshellcmd('python test.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
```

But it doesnt work.I cannot see output also.

How can I execute a python script with wamp on windows 10?

Thanks

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php (adapt first example on this page).

Comment: This sample works but I cant run python script. I trled this also.

Comment: Then please edit your question with the python source code.

Comment: It does not matter with source code. I tried test.py as content print("test").

Comment: Is this php file in the same directory as the python file ?

Comment: Yes it is in same directory.

Comment: You need to check php logs. The `exec` function outputs error too, be sure to look.

Comment: Go to command prompt in the same directory as the php file, and type `python test.py`. Does this execute without any errors ?

Comment: Yes it works in the command prompt.

Comment: Is this php snippet the whole script ? Perhaps it's inside an html comment I don't know :( Check the page source in browser. Also you can try `escapeshellcmd('python --version');` to check if it's a problem with the file.

Comment: Yes it is whole php. No html codes

Comment: What about the other test ? Did it print the python version ?

Comment: You mean exec("python --version") ?;

Comment: I've started a draft for the answer, check the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$output=null;
$retval=null;
exec('echo %PATH%', $output, $retval);
echo "Returned with status $retval and output:\n";
print_r($output);
?>
```

Also open a command prompt in the same directory as the php file and type `echo %PATH%`. Check if these 2 commands output the same value.

Comment: It does not return anything. But python exe fullpath returns version. I need to run python file which inside of project uplevel folder. So I need to set python file directory also.

Comment: Nice :) Updated answer.

Comment: It worked with full path. I didnt try but I think you should change ' as ".

Comment: You mean the string passed to `exec` ? No. The `%PATH%` is expanded on execution by Windows. If the full path worked it means `python`  (the language binary) directory isn't on `%PATH%`. If you want it to work without full path you have to add the directory where python is stored to `%PATH%`.

Comment: I mean php cant read a variable to inside of '.So it should be inside double quatos.

Comment: You are confusing `$PATH` with `%PATH%`. This one is parsed by windows not PHP, you can open a command prompt and type `echo %PATH%` as I directed you, then you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

After searching alot, i found this solution and it workes on wamp servers on windows:

```
<?php 

$test = shell_exec("C:\path_to_your_python.exe C:\path_to_python_script");
echo $test;

?>
```

For my case, it was:

```
<?php 

$test = shell_exec("C:\Users\oklas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe C:\Users\oklas\python\test.py");
echo $test;

?>
```